# passing a variable into style css for javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to set a margin-left using a variable in JavaScript. Is this possible? How can this be done?

The margin left needs to be the clientWidth of the text:

```
var hoverBubble = document.getElementById(id);
var linkWidth = link.clientWidth + 1;
hoverBubble.style.margin-left = linkWidth + 'px';
```

Comment: Did you notice the error in your browser's developer console?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, you just have to camelCase style properties.

```
hoverBubble.style.marginLeft = linkWidth + 'px';
```

---

You just can't use an hyphen (minus sign) as in the question.

Otherwise the interpreter will "think" that you have a subtraction operation in the left-side of the assignment, which results in a syntax error.

You can see that error on proper debugging tools, such as [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) (F12 in Chrome and select console) or [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) (Install Firebug and press F12 on Firefox).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
hoverBubble.style.marginLeft = linkWidth + 'px';
```